# Textbox value multiply by 100

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

multiply my model value to 100.
my model datatype is decimal.
I'll get decimal value in the output.

```
 @item.CURRENT_SOFT_MIN.ToString("0.00") &nbsp;&percnt;
```

Image here

[image]

Comment: Better to use `[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:P2}")]` for display percentage in `TextBox`/`TextBoxFor`, or use `@item.CURRENT_SOFT_MIN.ToString("P2")` for directly render percentage format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:P2}")]
for display percentage in TextBox/TextBoxFor, or use @item.CURRENT_SOFT_MIN.ToString("P2") for directly render percentage format